# PHP API Protection?

Tags: php, api, authentication, curl

I have a simple PHP API. I just used `cURL` for the Client and `$_POST` to accept the requests at the Server side. Something like ..

Client:

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.example.com/api-server");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('q' => 'world!'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER , 1);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo json_decode($response);
?>
```

Server:

```
<?php
echo json_encode("hello, ".$_POST["q"]);
?>
```

My questions here are:

- Am i even still following the standard API logic anyway?
- How to "PROTECT" this API Server Access?

Comment: "How to "PROTECT" this API Server Access?" --- like any other HTTP page. The dummy way: http basic auth. The advanced way: OAuth

Comment: LoL, seems it is so clear answer. Would you mind saying what are these? Bcos i asked for these things.

Comment: why don't you want to google for it? I've given you several keywords

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay i found it here for what i asked above:
http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php

It simply used, for API page:

```
if ( $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] == $MY_API_USER && $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'] == $MY_API_PW) {
    ..
    ..
} else {
    header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Sorry, this API is protected. You may need a valid authentication."');
    header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
    exit;
}
```

At the Caller/requester end, add this two lines into the `cURL` calls:

```
..
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $MY_API_USER.":".$MY_API_PWD);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
..
```

Thats simply all, for me.

Comment: I really recommend this solution. Also, I love the eloquence of your answer. It has very briefly implemented the protection solution - for which developers have written classes, etc. these days.

Answer (score 1):

Dont try & write an API engine, these are industry standard. Look at Soap or REST.

Here are some of the libraries out there that will do all the heavy lifting:

- Soap server http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.soap.server.html
- Soap client http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.soap.client.html
- Rest server
- Rest client

Then to protect these you could use basic http protection, through to  OAuth etc

Comment: You can also test your API server independently with SoapUI http://www.soapui.org (free download)

Comment: To be fair, there isn't anything inherently wrong with creating a RESTful API implementation, especially provided that it is for a purpose narrower than most generalized implementations or components can manage without too much kludging. But yea, don't reinvent the wheel either; use well tested components when you can.

Answer (score 0):

While there are well defined communication protocols such as HTTP, and transport formats such as JSON, the actual implementation of a API architecture is left to the developer.

Many existing tools, from complete frameworks to modular components, exist to assist in the construction of an API layer, but at the end of the day you need to build something that works.

If you need a server, focus on the server, and focus on an implementation that adheres to standards when available, and best practices otherwise; including facets such as resource architecture, authentication, and so forth.

Right now, you're spewing out some query parameter concatenated JSON. I doubt that's the intended final result, unless you're after an `echo` server.

Model your API after a service, or domain model; expose methods and properties as resources of your API layer.

**Addendum**: Oh, and as for "protection"; the already mentioned techniques of HTTP Basic or OAuth are good candidates, but as is the core of my answer: it depends on what you need.